# Vertical and Horizontal Shifts of Plots

Tags: plotting

I am trying to combine two plots in a way that the second plot will horizontally move to the point where the first one ends. So they will be touching each other at their end/starting points. I have tried some simple tricks and codes, but no success. The codes are as the followings:

```
Fig1 := Plot[10.9545 + Sqrt[100 - x^2]/2, {x, 0, 16}, PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0, 16}}];

Fig2 := Plot[Sqrt[120.` - 4.` x^2], {x, 0, 6}];

Show[Fig1, Fig2, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction,PlotLabel -> "Combined PPF"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/<code>Translate.html) to translate the graphics primitives of `Fig2` by a vector of your choice:

```
Show[Fig1, Fig2 /. l_Line :> Translate[l, {10, 0}], PlotRange -> All] (* or *)
Show[Fig1, Graphics[Translate[Fig2[[1]], {10, 0}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you create a translated version of `Fig2`:

```
Fig3 = Plot[Sqrt[120.` - 4.` (x - 10)^2], {x, 10, 16}];
Show[Fig1, Fig3, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks! Translate is the one that I have been looking for.

Comment: `@Ilker, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to define your function as having two parts using Piecewise, and then simply plot that combined function.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{10.9545 + Sqrt[100 - x^2]/2, 0 < x < 10},
                    {Sqrt[120.` - 4.` (x - 10)^2], 10 < x < 16}}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 16}]
```

[image]